# Trouble understanding a basic result from a supremum problem in Analysis I

Tags: real-analysis

I haven't asked a question here before so I hope I'm doing everything right since this is such a wonderful place to read. I'm going into my first course in Analysis this semester and I've been reading textbooks/watching youtube videos to get my head in the right place. I came across this result in a youtube video and I've been thinking about it a lot and I think I'm missing some information about the definition of the supremum (even though I've read it over and over in different textbooks).

The result simply states that if $A = [-3, 17)$ then the supremum has to be 17. But in the definition of the supremum it states that our least upper bound is greater than or equal to any element in our set, and 17 is surely greater than everything in our set but it isn't equal to any of them since the notation implies 17 isn't in our set! So my question can pretty much be summed up as: why isn't the least upper bound of a set just the largest element in that set? The definition doesn't say the supremum has to be in the set A, but it definitely can be in other examples I've seen.

I hope everyone is having a great day and is excited to go back to school soon!

Comment: The problem is that your set $A$  does not have a largest element.

Comment: Yes, $17$ isn't equal to any element of $[-3,17)$. But it is greater than any of its elements, right? So, it is equal or greater.

Comment: Interesting! So when a subset of the reals has a largest element that's defined in the subsets definition, then the supremum is that largest element. But if there isn't a defined largest element, then whatever real number is greater than all of the elements of the subset but lesser than any other upper bound is the supremum?

Comment: The statement "is greater than or equal " says it is greater  or maybe equal. if it is equal the supremum is also the maximum- The definition you mention is not the best, or not really a definition .  Better:  supremum  is the smallest upper bound.. and that is true for 17 in (-3,17)

Comment: If a set $A$ has a greatest element $a$ then *automatically* this $a\in A$ is also the supremum of $A$. But for having a supremum it is not necessary that $A$ has a greatest element. This is nicely illustrated be e.g. the set $A=[-3,17)$ which has $17\notin A$ as supremum. This because $17$ is an upper bound of $A$ and for every upperbound $b$ of $A$ it is true that $17\leq b$.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it! Thanks guys

Comment: @TheodoreBaum Another way to see it is to consider any number smaller than $17$. You know $17$ is greater than every element in the set but if a number $r\lt 17$, can it be greater than every number in the set?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be a set.A number $M$ is called $\mathit{Supremum}$ of $A$ if it satisfies the following two properties:
(i)Every element of $A$ should be less than or equal to $M$,i.e.,$x\le M$ for every $x \in A$.
(ii)Any number smaller than $M$ can not be an upper bound of $A$,i.e.,for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists an element $x \in A$ such that $M-\epsilon \lt x$.
If we take $A=[-3,17)$,then $x\le 17$ for every $x \in A$.And for any $\epsilon \gt 0$,we can find an element $x$ of $A$ such that $17-\epsilon \lt x$.Since $17$ satisfies the property of $\mathit{Supremum}$,we have $SupA=17$.The Supremum may or may not belong to a set.In this case it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to begin by asking the question, what exactly is the largest element in the set $A = [-3, 17)$? Let's call this element $x$. Is $x = 16.9$ or is $x = 16.99$? Perhaps $x = 16.999$. Maybe $x = 16.9999999$? We can't really get a value for $x$. But one thing is certain, whatever the value of $x$ is, imagining that it does exist, $x$ will always be less than $17$, i.e. $x <17$.

Now imagine the set $A = [-3, 17]$. What will be largest element $x$ in this set? That will be $17$ of course. We can see here that there is no element in $A$ that is greater than $17$. This leads us to the definition of the supremum of the set $A$.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. An element $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is called the **least upper bound** or **supremum** of $A$ if

1. $x \leq \alpha \; \forall x \in A$, i.e., $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$;
2. For any upper bound $\alpha'$ for $A$, $\alpha \leq \alpha'$

The supremum of $A$, can be denoted as $\sup{A}$.

And lastly, the least upper bound is greater than or equal to any element in the set. $17$ is certainly greater than $x, \forall x \in A$. The keyword here is **or**. $17$ is greater than **or** equal to all elements of A.

Hope this helps.